Use wpf translatetransform and didn't get the correct drawing
i give two point[(100, 100) and (500, 200)] to crate a rect with wpf streamgeometry. and i use translatetransform to translate the rect in grid center.
but draw the point(400, 400) and (2000, 800) and translate the rect to the grid center, the a right part of the rect was disapper.
How to fix this bug??
draw rect with point[(100, 100) and (500, 200)]
draw rect with point[(400, 400) and (2000, 800)]
private void DrawLineObjectTest(double _fScale = 1.0f)
        {
            Point ptStart = new Point(100.0f, 100.0f);
            Point ptEnd = new Point(500.0f, 200.0f);

            double fScale = _fScale;
            Path pathDraw1 = new Path();
            StreamGeometry sg1 = new StreamGeometry();
           
            sg1.FillRule = FillRule.Nonzero;
            pathDraw1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0, 0));
            pathDraw1.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
            pathDraw1.StrokeThickness = 1;
            pathDraw1.Fill = Brushes.Red;

            using (StreamGeometryContext ctx = sg1.Open())
            {
                double sx = ptStart.X * _fScale, sy = ptStart.Y * _fScale;
                double ex = ptEnd.X * _fScale, ey = ptEnd.Y * _fScale;


                ctx.BeginFigure(new Point(sx, (sy)), false, true);
                ctx.LineTo(new Point(ex, (sy)), true, false);
                ctx.LineTo(new Point(ex, (ey)), true, false);
                ctx.LineTo(new Point(sx, (ey)), true, false);
                ctx.LineTo(new Point(sx, (sy)), true, false);
            }
            sg1.Freeze();

            Rect boundary = sg1.Bounds;
            Point ptCenter = new Point();
            ptCenter.X = (boundary.Left + boundary.Right) / 2.0f;
            ptCenter.Y = (boundary.Top + boundary.Bottom) / 2.0f;

            Point ScreenCenter = new Point(gridDisplay.ActualWidth / 2.0f, gridDisplay.ActualHeight / 2.0f);

            TranslateTransform tr1 = new TranslateTransform(-ptCenter.X, -ptCenter.Y);
            TranslateTransform tr2 = new TranslateTransform(ScreenCenter.X, ScreenCenter.Y);
            TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();
            tg.Children.Add(tr1);
            tg.Children.Add(tr2);
            pathDraw1.Data = sg1;
            pathDraw1.RenderTransform = tg;
            gridDisplay.Children.Add(pathDraw1);
        }

xamlfile
<Grid x:Name="gridDisplay" Grid.Column="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}" MouseLeftButtonDown="gridDisplay_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="gridDisplay_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonUp="gridDisplay_MouseLeftButtonUp" Visibility="Visible" PreviewMouseWheel="gridDisplay_PreviewMouseWheel" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
            <Grid.OpacityMask>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFC1B1B1" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.OpacityMask>
        </Grid>

i try the use Measure and arrange, and it does't work

Perhaps your Grid is too small to host the whole shape of the Path at the original location and thus the part of the Path outside of the Grid won't be drawn despite you moved the Path by TranslateTransform. You can easily check it by expanding the Grid.
